# Current Location Update coding on google map not working in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to zoom camera on current location in google map android but my code is not working i have tried many method my gps location is on in phone this code works on emulator but not working in device i have tried onLocationChanged method also please any buddy suggest me a proper working solution

```
                mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
                mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,
                        0, mLocationListener);
                Criteria mCriteria = new Criteria();
                String bestProvider = String.valueOf(mLocationManager.getBestProvider(mCriteria, true));
                Location mLocation = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
                if (mLocation != null) {
                    Log.e("TAG", "GPS is on");
                    final double currentLatitude = mLocation.getLatitude();
                    final double currentLongitude = mLocation.getLongitude();
                    LatLng loc1 = new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);

                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude), 10));
                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 1000, null);
```

Comment: Can you try with this `mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000 * 60 * 1,
                        10, mLocationListener);` ? and let me know what you are getting

Comment: Ya sure i will try and let you know

Comment: This has happened with me. If the `mLocation` is null,immediately go to your Google maps on your device and see if the maps is able to fetch some location, if maps doesn't display the current location then it is some device problem. Restarting the device solved my problem.

Comment: No it is not device problem it is fetching location on google map properly

Comment: Ok in that case try my small code and let me know

Comment: Did you try it ? did it work ?

Answer (score 2):

```
protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();

    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude()))
            .zoom(10)
            .bearing(0.0f)
            .tilt(00.0f)
            .build();
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
            .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace :

```
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude), 10));
```

With:

```
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(loc1, 10));
```

Comment: but location always returns null

Comment: Did you ask for ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission from Manifest?

Comment: yes i have asked for both ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION

Comment: And also at the run-time ? you can check in your App Settings on your device whether the Location permission is toggled on? If not try toggling it on and then re-open the app. Or else the problem is something else

Comment: I have checked  and location is on

Comment: You're code seems to be ok. Check on location settings, set location mode to "High accurcy" then check again.